# I have a SMSgateway JavaScript API which I want to integrate with my website, somehow it doesn't seems to work

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

```
    <form onsubmit="return process()" method="post">
    <table style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1); border-radius:8px">
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" id="apname" placeholder="Name" required /></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Age:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="age" id="apage" placeholder="Age" required /></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Phone:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="phone" id="apphone" placeholder="For the OTP" onchange="return validation();" required /></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Date:</td>
        <td><input type="date" name="date" id="apdate" required /></td></tr>
    <tr>            
        <td></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-success" id="button" style="width:90px" type="submit">Proceed</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" style="width:90px" onclick="window.location.href='index.html'">Cancel</button></td></tr>
        <span id="err" style="color:#FF0000"></span>
    </table></form>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function process(){
    var mcAuthkey = "42A1zr6NGQ6ip";
    var theName = document.getElementById('#apname').value;
    var age = document.getElementById('#apage').value;
    var phone = document.getElementById('#apphone').value;
    var date = document.getElementById('#apdate').value;
    var msg = "theNam+ aged +age+ has booked for an appointment on +date+. Contact: +phone";
    var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "http://api.msg91.com/api/v2/sendsms",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
    "authkey": "mcAuthkey",
    "content-type": "application/json"
    },
    "processData": false,
    "data": "{ \"sender\": \"SOCKET\", \"route\": \"4\", \"country\": \"91\", \"sms\": [ { \"message\": \"msg\", \"to\": [ \"phone\" ] } ] }"
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    });
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want the 'process function' to be working when I submit my form. Any Idea what might be going wrong ? also I can't be using any framework or other server side languages. HTML + JavaScript is all I've got to use. Am building an android app with apache cordova.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you did not define a validation function, which you call upon changing the third field.

Since you are using the native document.getElementById, you pass in the element id without hash.

You should not quote mcAuthkey, since it is a variable.

Certainly, you already added jquery library to your html.

This REST api requires passing the right authentication key. I will not be able to test it. You must use a working authentication key.

**Edit**

A sample post call in their API:
http://api.msg91.com/api/v2/sendsms?authkey=YourAuthKey&mobiles=98260XXXXX,98261XXXXX&message=message&sender=senderid&route=4&country=0

Their instructions are [here](https://api.msg91.com/apidoc/textsms/send-sms-v1.php)

I had to update some of your fields to match the structure they have.

Below is an updated snippet

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="return process()" method="post">
    <table style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1); border-radius:8px">
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" id="apname" placeholder="Name" required /></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Country code:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="country" id="country" placeholder="Country code" required /></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Phone:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="phone" id="apphone" placeholder="For the OTP" onchange="return validation();" required /></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Date:</td>
        <td><input type="date" name="date" id="apdate" required /></td></tr>
    <tr>            
        <td></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-success" id="button" style="width:90px" type="submit">Proceed</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" style="width:90px" onclick="window.location.href='index.html'">Cancel</button></td></tr>
        <span id="err" style="color:#FF0000"></span>
    </table></form>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function validation(){
  return true;
}
function process(){
    var mcAuthkey = "42A1zr6NGQ6ip";
    var theName = document.getElementById('apname').value;
    var country = document.getElementById('country').value;
    var phone = document.getElementById('apphone').value;
    var date = document.getElementById('apdate').value;
    var msg = "theNam+ aged +age+ has booked for an appointment on +date+. Contact: +phone";
    var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "http://api.msg91.com/api/v2/sendsms",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
    "authkey": mcAuthkey,
    "content-type": "application/json"
    },
    "processData": false,
    "data": { 
     sender: "SOCKET", 
     route: "4",
     country: country, 
     flash:1, 
     sms: [ { "message: msg, to: phone} ] }
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    });
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh sorry.. actually the validation function has been defined in my code and that part is working fine, I trimmed it down in the question to clear the "too much of code" error which I received while I was trying to post this. Anyways lemme try out those points you have mentioned and will get back to you with the status.. thanks a ton in advance.. cheers

Comment: orabis.. I tried the snippet you provided, I passed the right authkey. I still don't find this working..

Comment: I made some changes to the answer and provided some links.

Comment: One more thing, make sure you are not on localhost in order to avoid cross-origin request errors.

Comment: Or alternatively, if you use Chrome, use the disable security flag: chrome --disable-web-security  --user-data-dir        But you have to be careful and use it for testing.

Comment: Perfect. Glad to help.